# (fixed myself) fetch data in database and store in a global variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I’ve been working the whole night to fix this problem but I can’t seem to figure it out. I am new to php and PDO. I was successful in creating a database with fields `id`, `firstname` and `lastname`.

On `id =1` the values of username and lastname is `Andrea` and `Bocelli`,
on `id=2` are `Sarah` and `Brightman`.

Now I want to fetch all the firstname and lastname on id1 and store it in a $_SESSION array variable and values of firstname and lastname of id2 in anoter $_SESSION array variable, for me to be able to access these variables in the other page. Here’s my code: (already edited and working)

```
$host   = "localhost";

$dbname = "try";

$user   = "root";

$pass   = "";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);

$statement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM members');

$statement->execute();

$count = $statement->rowCount();

$_SESSION['firstname']=array();

$_SESSION['lastname']=array();

for ($c=0, $c2=1;$c<$count;$c++, $c2++){

    $sql='SELECT firstname FROM members WHERE id=?';

    $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);

    $sth->execute(array($c2));

    $_SESSION['firstname'][$c]=$sth->fetchColumn();

    $sql='SELECT lastname FROM members WHERE id=?';

    $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);

    $sth->execute(array($c2));

    $_SESSION['lastname'][$c]=$sth->fetchColumn();

}
```

The problem now is this code only fetches the data on id1, obviously I only accessed id 1 inside the loop. What I want to do is the id number will increment every loop. I tried declaring a variable `$idupdate` with a value of  1 outside the loop and inside the loop on the part `WHERE id=$idupdate` then `&idupdate++`, but it doesn’t seem to work. What I want to achieve is fetch all the data in the entire column in id 1 and store it in an array variable accessible on the other page. How can I achieve this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

u need to call session_start(); before setting/accessing any session variable.
then u can access the session variables in another page again by first caling sesion_Start();

when done, call session_destroy();

Comment: i already did that, on top of all the codes is session_start(), but nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to declare your sessions as arrays.
Try something like this.

```
$_SESSION['id1']['firstname']=$firstname_id1; //
$_SESSION['id1']['lastname']=$lastname_id1;

$_SESSION['id2']['firstname']=$firstname_id2;
$_SESSION['id2']['lastname']=$lastname_id2;
```

What you are doing will overwrite the firstname and lastname.

```
$_SESSION['firstname'][$c]=$sth->fetchColumn();
```

I see that your for loop is not making much sense. How about something like this.

```
    <?php

session_start();
$host   = "localhost";

$dbname = "try";

$user   = "root";

$pass   = "";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);

$sql='SELECT firstname,lastname FROM members WHERE id=1';

$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute();

$_SESSION[]['firstname']=$sth->fetchColumn();
$_SESSION[]['lastname']=$sth->fetchColumn(1);

$sql='SELECT firstname,lastname FROM members WHERE id=2';

$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute();

$_SESSION[]['firstname']=$sth->fetchColumn();
$_SESSION[]['lastname']=$sth->fetchColumn(1);


?>
```

EDIT:

Store the first name and last name when you are inserting the row.

```
<?php

     session_start();
 $firstname = 'Mike';
 $lastname = 'Luther';

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname,lastname) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':firstname'=>$firstname,
                  ':lastname'=>$lastname));

$id = $db->lastInsertId('id');

$_SESSION[$id]['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION[$id]['lastname'] = $lastname;

    //i dont think you will need that $id variable. What i understand is that you just want to display the firstname and lastname.

   //you can just write

   $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;


?>
```

Comment: yes I tried that, but what I want to achieve is to automatically create another index in session array whenever i add new id, username and lastname. My site is something like displays the details of the members, and when a new member is added the new profile details will be also visible.

Comment: I still didnt understand your exact requirement. I am sorry for that.

Comment: I am sorry, I am using loop to get the number of rows means I am getting the number of ids, then store the first name and last name in an array variable, now when i add a new id example id is 3 with new values in first name and last name the loop will run again and store new data in the array variable, so whenever i add a new member in my site automatically the firstname and lastname will be visible.

Comment: I got that. So why dont use set the session valiable while adding the id, that when you insert the record. This will save you from running queries. I will edit the code and write the code or you. 2 minutes.

Comment: Kindly Consider ticking the answer, if it helped/solved your problem.

Comment: yes it works but it's not what i want to happen. I got it fixed myself now, thanks for your help. I already got it fixed myself, I edited the OP and code works now how I wanted it to. Thanks again!